# problems with GUIminer

Tags: guiminer

GUIminer doesn't work with certain CPU through the open CL, there is a specific error with core i3 3217 CPU, the internal GPU on them work well, but when trying to run it through CPU it gives IO error - 1, tolerance 2.
and on macs, it works on most chips, but on certain chips it freeze on the difficulty indicator, and it takes all the processing power, but there is no outcome, i might try downloading a different miner and working it through the guiminer, like the phoenix or the cgminer, instead of the open cl miner, I have tried mac miner, but the OS version of the macs i was working on were 10.6 and mac miner had some problems with that.

Comment: What's the error message you're trying to solve?

Comment: IO error 1 tolerance 2, I think i can avoid it by using solo option as server instead of others, but not sure if it always works

Comment: There is a specific version of MacMiner for 10.6 but note that GPU mining performance is terrible in 10.6 due to the system OpenCL implementation. You may also want to try running the compiled bfgminer (also available on the MacMiner site supporting 10.6+, which has a newer version than the 10.6 app)